# Pretty-print JSON document in Logstash 5

Tags: json, ruby, logstash

I am using Logstash 5 to ingest a file containing a set of JSON documents, extract part of each document in each event, and write them out to another file.

I want to pretty-print the output JSON. I found this thread: [How do I pretty-print JSON for an email body in logstash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32077228/how-do-i-pretty-print-json-for-an-email-body-in-logstash) which looked ideal, but Logstash 5 now prevents you from accessing event attributes directly, replacing it with event.get and event.set methods (see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-api.html).

I tried to convert the above as follows:

```
ruby  {
    init => "require 'json'"
    code => "@pretty_body = JSON.pretty_generate(event.get('body'))
             event.set('body', @pretty_body)
            "
}
```

but get

```
ERROR logstash.filters.ruby - Ruby exception occurred: only generation of JSON objects or arrays allowed
```

What is the correct LS5 equivalent of the above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for the following:

```
filter {
  ruby  {
    init => "require 'json'"
    code => "event.set('message', JSON.pretty_generate(JSON.parse(event.get('message'))))"
  }
}
```

Here is my test and the result:

```
input: {"make_me_pretty":"test"}
{
    "@timestamp" => 2017-03-22T04:56:00.118Z,
      "@version" => "1",
       "message" => "{\n  \"make_me_pretty\": \"test\"\n}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @fylie! I'm posting this as another answer as I needed to adjust what I was doing a bit.

My problem was that the input document is a JSON document wrapped in another JSON document, so the inner doc is one field in the outer doc, which contains metadata. So "message" contains more than I want to write to the file.

I was hung up on trying to reduce the document to only what I wanted, by parsing the inner doc field with the json filter up to the top level, removing everything else, and then pretty-printing what remained. So I had nothing left to use in the Ruby filter.

To fix this, I keep everything, don't parse the inner doc field using the json filter, pretty print it with the ruby filter instead, and output to file just that field using the { format => %{fieldname} } option in the file output plugin, and it works as desired.

Answer (score 0):

The question says you want to pretty-print the JSON output to *another file*. Just use the [File Output plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-file.html) with the rubydebug codec:

```
output {
    file {
         path => "./output/outputFile.json"
         codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

(I'm using logstash 7.15.2.)